# applesimutils --list returns empty list [] after MacOS Mojave and Xcode 11.3 update

Tags: detox

**Describe the bug**

After upgrading my MacOS from High Sierra to Mojave and Xcode from 10.x to 11.3, I'm no longer able to run the Detox test.. It gives me this error below about not having iOS simulators.

**DetoxRuntimeError: Failed to find a device by UDID = "7C50BE35-0CDE-413A-A08D-784E98C61010" and by type = "iPhone 11 Pro"

```
HINT: Run 'applesimutils --list' to list your supported devices. It is advised only to specify a device type, e.g., "iPhone Xʀ" and avoid explicit search by OS version.

  at SimulatorDriver._queryDevices (../node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/SimulatorDriver.js:224:13)**
```

So I ran applesimutils --list command and received empty list like below.
[

]

But if I run **xcrun simctl list devices** then I get the list of devices pertaining to iOS 13.3

**To Reproduce**

- [Yes] I have tested this issue on the latest Detox release and it still reproduces

Provide the steps necessary to reproduce the issue. If you are seeing a regression, try to provide the last known version where the issue did not reproduce.

1. Upgrade MacOS from High Sierra to Mojave and Xcode from 10.x to 11.3 (latest)
2. Run "detox text"
3. Got this error
   DetoxRuntimeError: Failed to find a device by UDID = "7C50BE35-0CDE-413A-A08D-784E98C61010" and by type = "iPhone 11 Pro"

HINT: Run 'applesimutils --list' to list your supported devices. It is advised only to specify a device type, e.g., "iPhone Xʀ" and avoid explicit search by OS version.

```
  at SimulatorDriver._queryDevices (../node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/SimulatorDriver.js:224:13)
```

4. Ran applesimutils --list command. Received an empty list
   [
   ]
5. But if I run **xcrun simctl list devices** then I get the list of devices pertaining to iOS 13.3. I even changed my package.json to reflect the latest migration guide link below and included the device object - https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Migration.md

This is how my package.json looks like

```
"detox": {
"configurations": {
  "ios.sim.debug": {
    "type": "ios.simulator",
    "binaryPath": "build/native/QuickSightiOS-2.0.2096.d.d.app",
    "build": "xcodebuild -project ios/quicksight-react-native-mobile-tests.xcodeproj    -scheme quicksight-react-native-mobile-tests -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
    "device": {
      "type": "iPhone 11 Pro",
      "id": "7C50BE35-0CDE-413A-A08D-784E98C61010"
    }
  }
},
"test-runner": "jest"
},`
```

6. I went to this website https://github.com/wix/AppleSimulatorUtils and reran the applesimutils commands again..

brew tap wix/brew
brew install applesimutils

After running the 2nd command above, i got this error

**4c32759b84a9:QuicksightReactNativeMobileTests kondurc$ brew install applesimutils
Updating Homebrew...
Error: applesimutils: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/wix/homebrew-brew/applesimutils.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected <<, expecting end
<<<<<<< HEAD
^~

## /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/wix/homebrew-brew/applesimutils.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected ===, expecting end

^~~
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/wix/homebrew-brew/applesimutils.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected >>, expecting end

> > > > > > > Detox Instruments 1.9.9...
> > > > > > >               ^~
> > > > > > >               /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/wix/homebrew-brew/applesimutils.rb:24: unexpected fraction part after numeric literal
> > > > > > >               Detox Instruments 1.9.9876**

**Expected behavior**
I would expect applesimutils --list command to show the list of simulators supported and eventually my detox test to run successfully instead of complaining about failing to find the device type.

**Environment (please complete the following information):**
 - Detox: 14.9.2
 - React Native: 0.60.4
 - Node: v10.15.1
 - Device: iPhone 11 Pro (simulator)
 - Xcode: 11.3
 - iOS: 13.3
 - macOS: Mojave

**Device and Verbose Detox Logs**
4c32759b84a9:QuicksightReactNativeMobileTests kondurc$ detox test --loglevel trace
detox[63893] INFO:  [test.js] configuration="ios.sim.debug" loglevel="trace" reportSpecs=true DETOX_START_TIMESTAMP=1578349653101 node_modules/.bin/jest --config e2e/config.json '--testNamePattern=^((?!:android:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 "e2e"
detox[63894] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:50258...
detox[63894] DEBUG: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_OPEN] opened web socket to: ws://localhost:50258
detox[63894] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_SEND] {"type":"login","params":{"sessionId":"6d94b773-5329-fab7-89ae-add64e14cdec","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}
detox[63894] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=tester, sessionId=6d94b773-5329-fab7-89ae-add64e14cdec
detox[63894] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=tester, sessionId=6d94b773-5329-fab7-89ae-add64e14cdec
detox[63894] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE] {"type":"loginSuccess","params":{"sessionId":"6d94b773-5329-fab7-89ae-add64e14cdec","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}

detox[63894] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #0] applesimutils --list --byId 7C50BE35-0CDE-413A-A08D-784E98C61010 --byType "iPhone 11 Pro"
detox[63894] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #0] [

]

detox[63894] ERROR: [DetoxExportWrapper.js/DETOX_INIT_ERROR]

DetoxRuntimeError: Failed to find a device by UDID = "7C50BE35-0CDE-413A-A08D-784E98C61010" and by type = "iPhone 11 Pro"

HINT: Run 'applesimutils --list' to list your supported devices. It is advised only to specify a device type, e.g., "iPhone Xʀ" and avoid explicit search by OS version.
    at SimulatorDriver._queryDevices (/Users/kondurc/Desktop/quicksightmobiletests/src/QuicksightReactNativeMobileTests/node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/SimulatorDriver.js:224:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
detox[63894] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onAfterAll()
detox[63894] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=tester, sessionId=6d94b773-5329-fab7-89ae-add64e14cdec
detox[63894] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/WS_CLOSE] Detox server connections terminated gracefully
 FAIL  e2e/specs/signinWithADUserTests.spec.js
  Sign In using Enterprise AD User - Reader role
    ✕ Should verify app is launched and Sign In button is available (4ms)
    ✕ Should Sign In with valid AD user from a reader group (15ms)
    ✕ Should enter Settings View Page (2ms)
    ✕ Should Sign Out (1ms)

● Sign In using Enterprise AD User - Reader role › Should verify app is launched and Sign In button is available

```
DetoxRuntimeError: Failed to find a device by UDID = "7C50BE35-0CDE-413A-A08D-784E98C61010" and by type = "iPhone 11 Pro"

HINT: Run 'applesimutils --list' to list your supported devices. It is advised only to specify a device type, e.g., "iPhone Xʀ" and avoid explicit search by OS version.

  at SimulatorDriver._queryDevices (../node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/SimulatorDriver.js:224:13)
```

● Sign In using Enterprise AD User - Reader role › Should verify app is launched and Sign In button is available

```
ReferenceError: device is not defined

   7 | describe('Sign In using Enterprise AD User - Reader role', () => {
   8 |   beforeEach(async () => {
>  9 |     await device.launchApp();
     |           ^
  10 |   });
  11 |   
  12 |   it('Should verify app is launched and Sign In button is available', async () => {

  at device (specs/signinWithADUserTests.spec.js:9:11)
  at tryCatch (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
  at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
  at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
  at tryCatch (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
  at invoke (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:20)
  at ../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:11
  at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:16)
  at AsyncIterator.enqueue (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:13)
  at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
  at Object.<anonymous>.exports.async (../node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:216:14)
  at Object._callee (specs/signinWithADUserTests.spec.js:8:14)
```

Comment: Read the read me of applesimutils.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the readme:

https://github.com/wix/AppleSimulatorUtils#troubleshooting

> If Homebrew complains about a conflict in the wix/brew tap, run `brew untap wix/brew && brew tap wix/brew` and try installing again

Then upgrade applesimutils normally.